# Difference between char[] and char* in C

Tags: c, string, variable-declaration

I'm currently learning C and am having a bit of trouble understanding how to declare a string. I understand that in C, strings are simply arrays of characters. I've seen two different ways for declaring a string:

```
char[] some_string = "hello world";
```

and

```
char *some_string = "hello world";
```

When should each of these be used? Most code I've seen uses the char *some_string syntax, but I'm sure that there's a reason why. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that this is pretty much the same thing. char[] is (internally) treated as char*. *(char + i) == char[i] == *(i + char) == i[char]

Comment: @Beko: that's really not true; arrays are not simply pointers.  Your identity is more or less valid; you can't use `char` as a variable name, of course.  But given `int i = 2; char *ptr = "str";` then `*(ptr + i)` ≡ `ptr[i]` ≡ `*(i + ptr)` ≡ `i[ptr]`.  Given `char array[20];`, places where arrays differ from pointers include the type of `&ptr` (which is `char **`) vs type of `&array` (which is `char (*)[20]` — pointer to array of `char` of size 20), and `sizeof(ptr)` (typically 4 on a 32-bit system, 8 on a 64-bit system) vs `sizeof(array)` (which is 20 on all systems).

Answer (score 1):

`char some_string[] = "foo"` declares a local array of size 4 which is initialized at run time with the values 'f', 'o', 'o', and '\0'.  That memory is (probably) on the stack of the function.  `char *some_string = "foo"` declares a pointer which is initialized to the location of a string which is initialized at compile time to the same values.  The string `char [] some_string = "foo"` is a syntax error.  The most relevant difference between the two is that, on many platforms, the latter is not writable.  In other words, `some_string[1] = 'a'` will generate a segfault on some platforms if some_string was declared as a pointer rather than an array.